# can i rewrite url in tomcat 8 to a different domain (not redirect)?

Tags: tomcat, url-rewriting

just inherited a tomcat server - stuck with it for the foreseeable - and on an old version! I have one days experience of tomcat and have been reading through docs/google to no avail.

I have host domaina.com and host domainb.com

When a user goes to https://domaina.com/v i want that to rewrite to https://domainb.com (but keep the original url in the browser)

I've enabled the redirect valve in tomcat - I've also created a rewrite.config in the WEB-INF dir - I can confirm changes to these are being read.
the contents of the rewrite.config are:

```
RewriteRule ^/v$ https://domainb.com [R]
```

now this redirects the url but also changes the url in the browser - I've tried also using [P] instead of [R] as above but this fails totally (404)
I have read some misc blogs that suggest this might not be possible with tomcat unless I install apache and set that as a reverse proxy... however before I try this I'm hoping someone will point me in the right (better) direction
many thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `[P]` flag is not available in Apache Tomcat, see [the docs](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-10.0-doc/rewrite.html) for the full list of parameters.

In Apache HTTP Server, [the `[P]` flag](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_p) enables the `mod_proxy` module that allows to proxy requests to a different domain. Apache Tomcat doesn't have this functionality. So indeed you need an additional Apache HTTP Server (or a similar tool) to act as a reverse proxy to achieve what you want.